# How do I translate a view's "Menu tab"

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I am on Drupal 7.56 on a multilingual site.

I have created a view that contains tab menu links. Almost all the site it available now in two languages. But I still can't **translate those view tab menu links**.

I use those tabs to let users access some information via their account area

**Example** : in a view that contents articles (that I want to user to see only those they created) I add a menu link this way :

- link       : "user/%/myarticles".
- Menu name  : My Articles
- Menu type  : menu tab
- Menu "Menu : User menu

I have translated the view but I can not find any way to translate the "Menu name", not even in "admin/config/regional/translate/translate".

Users will see "My Articles" in both languages when I want them to see it written in the correct language in each case.

How do I present the user with only the correctly translated tab?

Answer (score 1):

The first steps when dealing with translations, particularly with user entered strings like Views Tabs labels, is to clear the cache and visit the page showing the string in question but make sure you **visit in a language other than English**!

The visit to that page with the interface in another language will trigger Drupal to refresh the Translate Interface list, and you should be able to find the new string when doing a search there (`admin/config/regional/translate/translate`).

Remember that the Translate Interface search is case sensitive! You *have to* enter "My Articles" and not "my articles" or any other case style.

If that search still isn't giving you any results, it may be you're missing a module that enables those strings to be included in translations. Make sure you have "String translation" or perhaps even "Variable translation" enabled.

If you've just enabled "String translation", similar to above, visit the page in another language then search for the string in Translate interface.